# DependencyProperty CoerceValueCallback with generic

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, dependency-properties

I'm building a wpf control that use DependencyProperty with generic, for which I need (at least I think) a CoerceValueCallback to check if the value is correct.
The idea is to build a base class from which I'll derive with number type.

```
public class MyClass<T> : Control where T : struct
{

    public T Value
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(T),
        typeof(MyClass<T>),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, null, CoerceValue)
    );


    private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        // Check if value is valid
        return verifiedValue;
    }
}


public class MyDerivedClass : MyClass<int>
{

}
```

Problem is that the CoerceValue is returning an object and I can't find how to return a generic instead.

Any idea ?

**EDIT:** Here is what I did thanks to the answers below

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> : Control where T : struct, IComparable
{

    public T MinValue { get; set; }
    public T MaxValue { get; set; }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(T),
        typeof(MyClass<T>),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(T), null, CoerceValue)
    );


    private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        T value = (T)baseValue;
        ((MyClass<T>)d).CoerceValueToBounds(ref value);

        return value;
    }

    private void CoerceValueToBounds(ref T value)
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(MinValue) < 0)
            value = MinValue;
        else if (value.CompareTo(MaxValue) > 0)
            value = MaxValue;
    }
}
```

This way, I can limit the Value within MinValue and MaxValue and keeping everything with generic, thus avoiding overriding an abstract method in every derived class.

Comment: what happened when you changed the return value to `T`?

Comment: In what sense "return a generic"?

Comment: "private static T CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
      // Check if value is valid
       return verifiedValue;
}"

With this, Visual studio tells me that the method has the wrong return type

Comment: How can a value be invalid here? You don't need a CoerceValueCallback.

Comment: the value has to stay in a given range. The Corcevalue is supposed to check that

Comment: And that range is the same for any T? if T is byte, int, short, long, double, decimal - range is still the same?

Comment: @Evk no, the range is set on the derived class

Comment: Then Clemens answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your control can utilize the generic, when using the [CoerceValueCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx), you will have to maintain the delegate callback. The [C# documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx) specifies that delegates are sealed.

I also noticed you have an issue with your `PropertyMetadata`. You are passing null as the default value. Which is what caught me off guard when I previously checked for null. Here is the code that worked for me when I tested it:

```
public class MyClass<T> : Control where T : struct
{
    public T Value
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(T),
        typeof(MyClass<T>),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(T), null, CoerceValue) //Must pass default(T) otherwise an exception will occur.
    );

    private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var tValue = (T)baseValue;
        // Check if tValue is valid 
        return tValue;
    }
}
```

Once you have the value returned from the CoerceValue method, you will have to cast it to T.

Comment: Did you notice `where T : struct`? Checking for `null` is pointless.

Comment: `baseValue as T` will not compile.

Comment: That cast does indeed work @ClémentPlantec. I noticed another issue with your code that I addressed in my answer.

Comment: @techvice Indeed, your solution works like a charm, thanks !

Comment: @ClémentPlantec Now how does the actual range check work here?

Answer (score 1):

Add an abstract `CoerceValue` method like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> : Control where T : struct
{
    ...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(T), typeof(MyClass<T>),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(T), null, CoerceValue));

    protected abstract T CoerceValue(T value);

    private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        return ((MyClass<T>)d).CoerceValue((T)value);
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyClass<int>
{
    protected override int CoerceValue(int value)
    {
        return Math.Max(100, Math.Min(200, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass "null" to PropertyMetadata as default value, because T is struct.

Comment: Works well too, but a bit cumbersome as I would have to override the abstract method for each derived class. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm still curious how a range check would work without such an abstract method.